# Best table structure for tracking state changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I'm currently trying to model an aspect of a system whereby components that are stored can change state, eg OK, FAILED, REPAIRED etc. On the web side I will need to show the current state, but also the history of previous (if any) states.

I'm torn between these two designs, could anyone shed any light on the best way (I'm more a software dev than a dba guy).

Option one:

statehistory table which tracks each time the state changes, the highest sequence number will be the current state : [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8555)

Option two:
Similar to above, except the current state is stored in the component table, and only past states are in the history table. When state is changed the current state is inserted as the most recent in history then the current is set in the component table: [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3edbfa)

As an aside, use either one or two but without the state lookup table, just store the state text as varchar (my thinking is this makes it easier to report from?): [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e3ab)

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

There are several component tables, should the state history table contain the data for all of them, or make a statehistory table per component? Each components table will have hundreds of thousands of entries, making the statehistory table pretty large.

eg: 
 Table:    component_a
 Table:    component_b
 etc..
 statehistory (
 component_a_id,
 component_b_id,
 state_id,
 ...
 )

Comment: Personally, I would opt for http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8555 - However, I would opt for a `DATETIME` instead of an int `SEQUENCE`

Comment: Any specific reason for datetime over int for the sequence?

Comment: The `DATETIME` would give more information than an `INT` would. The `DATETIME` would indicate most recent by `MAX` (as with the `INT`), but it will actually tell you WHEN. Again, my opinion.

Comment: Good point - I'll probably use this then. I did intend to have a "statechange" field which would be datetime, I suppose this would kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to do a hybrid between the two. I always store all state changes including the current state in the history table. That gives you a central place to query them. You can have a column `IsCurrent BIT NOT NULL` to make your life a little easier. Create a filtered unique index with filter `IsCurrent = 1` to enforce basic integrity rules.

I also store the current state in the main table. Probably not just a copy but as a foreign key to the history table. That makes for very convenient querying. Looking up the current state is often useful. For indexing reasons you can also duplicate the values into the main table, of course. The more duplication you have the more error prone the system.

If you want to avoid duplication but still index on the current status, you can create an indexed view to combine main and history tables. You can then create an index on mixed columns from both tables (e.g. on (`StatusHistoryItems.Status`, `Components.Name`) to support queries that ask for customers with a specific status and a specific name. This query would be resolved as a single index seek on the view's index).

You'd create a view like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Components c
JOIN StatusHistoryItems shi on c.ID = shi.ComponentID
     AND c.IsCurrent = 1 --this condition will join exactly one row
```

And index it. Now you have the current status together with all component data in one efficient index. No duplication, no denormalization at all. Just make sure that there is at least one status row for each customer with `IsCurrent = 1`.

I recommend having a nightly validation job that validates data consistency and alerts you of problems. Denormalized data has a habit of becoming corrupted over time for various reasons.

Comment: I like the idea of storing an fk to the history table from component for the current - I hadn't thought of that, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, I will use your suggestions. I've added an extra question to my original - do you have an opinion on that? Thanks.

Comment: I's rather merge the component tables if that is logically appropriate. "will have hundreds of thousands of entries, making the statehistory table pretty large" Don't fall into the trap of splitting tables hoping that smaller data sets are faster. Instead, apply proper indexing and the size of the tables will not matter. It is very rare that you have to sacrifice the purity of the data model on the altar of performance. You most likely are not in such a case.

Comment: Assuming that you don't want the merge the component tables: The clean solution is one history table per component table. That allows you to have the obvious primary and foreign keys. A very standard and well-understood schema with strong enforced integrity. I'd only deviate from that model for a good reason. Do you think there is any?

Comment: I can't merge the component tables as that wouldn't really fit correctly. My concern was that having one history table for them all then an fk into the components, for each row in the history table there will be one populated fk field, then x number of nulls. You're right about the data size, I'm fairly new to index design so I think i need to really read up on that to ensure decent performance.

Comment: You can also do the one history table approach (maybe with a CHECK constraint to enforce exactly one FK column to be set). It is not horrible. I'd just not do it without a reason. Certainly a bad reason would be to reduce the number of tables or to save the work of creating multiple history tables. That will not pay off.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46499/discussion-between-chris-l-and-usr)

Comment: "I also store the current state in the main table. Probably not just a copy but as a foreign key to the history table." This is great idea. Using a trigger in the "history" table to update the current state in the "primary" table. Thank you for this!